# How to get a count of users based on level id

Tags: php, sql, zend-framework

I am using zend framework and I am trying to get the number of users with level id of 11. I am very new to Zend and have not used their DB query format. I can do it in straight SQL, but I want to keep in their format. Any suggestions would be awesome.

```
$select = $table->select()
    ->setIntegrityCheck(false)
    ->from(array('u' => $table->info('name')), array('cnt' => 'COUNT(u.user_id)'))
    ->where('level_id = ?', 11)
    ->where('approved = ?', 1)
    ->where('verified = ?', 1)
    ->where('enabled = ?', 1);
```

This simply returns 1, it should be 251

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look this.

```
$select = $db->select()
    ->setIntegrityCheck(false)
    ->from($table->info('name'), array('ctn'=>'COUNT(user_id)'))
    ->where('level_id = ?', 11)
    ->where('approved = ?', 1)
    ->where('verified = ?', 1)
    ->where('enabled = ?', 1);

$result = $db->fetchRow($select);
echo $result["ctn"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Even simpler :

```
$select = $db->select()
->setIntegrityCheck(false) //really necessary ?
->from($table->info('name'), 'COUNT(user_id)' )
->where('level_id = ?', 11)
->where('approved = ?', 1)
->where('verified = ?', 1)
->where('enabled = ?', 1);
```

$result = $db->fetchOne($select);
echo $result;